# Can we cast a generic object to a custom object type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

For example, I already have this object somewhere in the code, it is a generic object:

```
var person1={lastName:"Freeman",firstName:"Gordon"};
```

I have the constructor for a Person object:

```
function Person(){
 this.getFullName=function(){
  return this.lastName + ' ' + this.firstName;
 }
}
```

Is there a simple syntax that allows us to convert person1 to an object of type Person?

Comment: There is no casting in JavaScript so ... short answer is no. Longer answer is ... still no. This is because the [[prototype]] can only be set when an object is created. However, one can monkey-patch on (copy over) methods/properties from Person to person1, which is an approach used by some "class frameworks" anyway. I would likely just create a *new* Person from person1 in a "copy-constructor".

Answer (score 67):

Nowadays we can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (*credits to @SayanPal's solution*) & ES6 syntax:

```
class Person {
  constructor(obj) {
    obj && Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
  
  getFullName() {
    return `${this.lastName} ${this.firstName}`;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const newPerson = new Person(person1)
newPerson.getFullName() // -> Freeman Gordon
```

### Old answer

You can use the copy-constructor way like @user166390 said in the comments.

```
function Person(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        // for safety you can use the hasOwnProperty function
        this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var newPerson = new Person(person1);
console.log(newPerson.getFullName()); // -> Freeman Gordon
```

Using a shorter version, 1.5 liner:

```
function Person() {
    if (arguments[0]) for (var prop in arguments[0]) this[prop] = arguments[0][prop];
}
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uhWs/1/)

Comment: Props for the "1.5 liner" version, love it.

Comment: But this answer is in effect just writing the `extend` function most frameworks have in there... And `Object.assign` is the replacement for that function... As of today. only Internet Explorer and Safari <= 9 don't support it. What I would do is grab an [Object.assign polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) and use it when the real Object.assign is not there. In my project I have a piece of code that checks the features needed and if any are missing, loads a second script with polyfills in it for these features.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I must agree on using `Object.assign` over this solution. See @SayanPal's solution which uses the assign method. I will update this answer sometime ;)

Comment: I don't like the question. JS doesn't use classes or casting, it uses functions to create objects -constructors-, it uses prototypes instead of classes.
I like the Object.assign approach which is a function that copies the properties from one object to another.
I'd like to say that sometimes you only need the @type, see [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/).

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

But if you're looking to treat your `person1` object as if it were a `Person`, you can call methods on `Person`'s prototype on `person1` with `call`:

```
Person.prototype.getFullNamePublic = function(){
    return this.lastName + ' ' + this.firstName;
}
Person.prototype.getFullNamePublic.call(person1);
```

Though this obviously won't work for privileged methods created inside of the Person constructor—like your `getFullName` method.

Answer (score 7):

This is not exactly an answer, rather sharing my findings, and hopefully getting some critical argument for/against it, as specifically I am not aware how efficient it is.

I recently had a need to do this for my project. I did this using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), more precisely it is done something like this:`Object.assign(new Person(...), anObjectLikePerson)`.

Here is link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/452zy6zd/), and also the main part of the code:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;

  this.getFullName = function() {
    return this.lastName + ' ' + this.firstName;
  }
}

var persons = [{
  lastName: "Freeman",
  firstName: "Gordon"
}, {
  lastName: "Smith",
  firstName: "John"
}];

var stronglyTypedPersons = [];
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  stronglyTypedPersons.push(Object.assign(new Person("", ""), persons[i]));
}
```

Comment: This syntax is very nice and efficient. Probably the way to go too. [Too bad some browsers don't support it yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: @A1rPun pollyfill can be used in those cases: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign

Comment: This is the best answer. The differences between assign() and create() are 1) assign works with non-object properties; 2) assign ignores unknown properties.

Answer (score 2):

This borrows from a few other answers here but I thought it might help someone. If you define the following function on your custom object, then you have a factory function that you can pass a generic object into and it will return for you an instance of the class.

```
CustomObject.create = function (obj) {
    var field = new CustomObject();
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (field.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            field[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }

    return field;
}
```

Use like this

```
var typedObj = CustomObject.create(genericObj);
```

Comment: I used a custom class extended from a standard one. Now, when a global listener's callback completed it returns a standard classed object as  a parameter. What was me doing is I tried all the answers matching my needs. I.e. TO EMBED  that 'standard' object to one designed by me. . Finally this answer helped!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a wrap up of Sayan Pal answer in a shorter form, ES5 style :

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.bar = undefined;
    this.buzz = undefined;
}

var foo = Object.assign(new Foo(),{
    bar: "whatever",
    buzz: "something else"
});
```

I like it because it is the closest to the very neat object initialisation in .Net:

```
var foo = new Foo()
{
    bar: "whatever",
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. It's simple for simple objects.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  getFullName() {
    return this.lastName + " " + this.firstName;
  }

  static class(obj) {
    return new Person(obj.firstName, obj.lastName);
  }
}

var person1 = {
  lastName: "Freeman",
  firstName: "Gordon"
};

var gordon = Person.class(person1);
console.log(gordon.getFullName());
```

I was also searching for a simple solution, and this is what I came up with, based on all other answers and my research. Basically, class Person has another constructor, called 'class' which works with a generic object of the same 'format' as *Person*.
I hope this might help somebody as well.

Comment: Be wise, avoid the reserved word `class` for the name of your conversion method! I'd suggest going for something like `Person.fromObject(obj)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a way if you like.
1st make an object with your all desire properties.
Then Call this object with your custom values.
Here is link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shaponpal/cb29gmu8/58/), and also the main part of the

```js
 function Message(obj) {
  this.key = Date.now();
  this.text = "";
  this.type = "client";
  this.status = 0;
  this.senderID = "";
  this.name = "";
  this.photoURL = "";
  this.metaData = [];
  this.time = new Date().toISOString();
  
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }else{
        this.metaData = [ ...this.metaData, {[prop]: obj[prop]} ];
    }
  }
}

 const getAllMessages = function (messages=[]) {
  var newMessages = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    newMessages.push(new Message(messages[i]));
  }
  return newMessages;
};

var messages = [{
  name: "Jhon",
  text: "Hello 1"
}, {
  name: "Smith",
  text: "Hello 2",
  meta1: "meta data 1"
}];

console.log("Single Instances", new Message(messages[0]));

console.log("Multiple Instances",getAllMessages(messages));
```